# Is there a Ruby Message Bus gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, message-bus

I am currently building an architechture with a rails process and multiple worker processes which need to be informed of certain events (like the creation of an object).

```
Rails
  |         API   Worker  
  +----------o------o--------o------ - - -
                        Some other
                          daemon
```

I'd like to do the following

```
class Article
  after_creation do
    MessageBus.send type: "article-created", id: self.id
  end
end
```

While the processes (API, Worker, Daemons, ...) just subscribe to the message bus and a block is called when a message comes in.

```
MessageBus.subscribe do |msg|
  if msg['type'] == 'article-created'
    # if this is my websocket daemon, I would push the article to the browser
    # if this is my indexing daemon, I would reindex the full-text search
    # if this is ... you get the deal.
  end
end
```

Currently I am using a local unix domain socket where I push JSON in with `UNIXSocket` and get it with `EventMachine.start_unix_domain_server`. But that allows only two-way communication. I also thought about using resque, but this is more a message queue while I need a bus. And it depends on redis. I am quite sure there must be a gem, that implements some message bus in ruby, but googling did not lead to any result

Comment: Did you try EventMachine channels? http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Channel.html

Comment: +1 for EventMachine channels. Another thing to consider (if your workers are running in the same process space as the master) is that Ruby has native support for the Observer pattern a la [Observable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html)

Comment: see: https://github.com/SamSaffron/message_bus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I hacked a quick own solution using Eventmachine Channels.

This is my server. Basically a clients connect to `/tmp/messagebus.sock` and send data. Everything that is pushed into the socket is sent to all other clients.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'

module Messagebus
  class Server
    attr_accessor :connections
    attr_accessor :channel

    def initialize
      @connections = []
      @channel = EventMachine::Channel.new
    end

    def start
      @signature = EventMachine.start_unix_domain_server '/tmp/messagebus.sock', Connection do |conn|
        conn.server = self
      end
    end

    def stop
      EventMachine.stop_server(@signature)

      unless wait_for_connections_and_stop
        EventMachine.add_periodic_timer(1) { wait_for_connections_and_stop }
      end
    end

    def wait_for_connections_and_stop
      if @connections.empty?
        EventMachine.stop
        true
      else
        puts "Waiting for #{@connections.size} connection(s) to finish ..."
        false
      end
    end
  end

  class Connection < EventMachine::Connection
    attr_accessor :server

    def post_init
      log "Connection opened"
    end

    def server=(server)
      @server = server

      @subscription = server.channel.subscribe do |data|
        self.log "Sending #{data}"
        self.send_data data 
      end
    end

    def receive_data(data)
      log "Received #{data}"
      server.channel.push data
    end

    def unbind
      server.channel.unsubscribe @subscription
      server.connections.delete(self)
      log "Connection closed"
    end

    def log(msg)
      puts "[#{self.object_id}] #{msg}"
    end
  end
end

EventMachine::run {
  s = Messagebus::Server.new
  s.start
  puts "New server listening"
}
```